# How to use "respective" instead of "respectively"?

Tags: adjectives

Original example:

> Connectors A and B should be attached to ends C and D of a cable respectively.

I would like to know how to rewrite this example when the ends have no name.  My rewritten example is as follows:

Rewritten example:

> Connectors A and B should be attached to respective ends of a cable.

I am unsure whether the usage of the "respective" is correct.  I think "different", "separate", or "corresponding" may be more suitable than "respective" .

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate) [What is the difference between “respective” and “corresponding”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/153788/9161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the adjective in the sentence as follows is grammatical:

Connectors A and B should be attached to the respective ends of the cable.

Alternatively, you can also say "..........to their own ends of the cable".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express the idea that A connects with C and B connects with D:

> Connectors A and B on cable 1 should be attached to connectors C and
>   D, respectively, on cable 2.
>
> Put the shirts and trousers on shelves three and four, respectively. When you're finished  putting the items on their respective shelves, you can sort the ties by color.

Shirts go to shelf three.  Trousers go to shelf four.

Comment: I have to upvote for your shirts and trousers example which is a nice demonstration of the difference in usage.